# Is it possible to test the google customer review badge on the local machine

Tags: javascript, google-api, development-environment

So i have used the following code to implement the customer reviews badge.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderBadge"
  async defer>
</script>

<script>
  window.renderBadge = function() {
    var ratingBadgeContainer = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(ratingBadgeContainer);
   window.gapi.load('ratingbadge', function() {
     window.gapi.ratingbadge.render(
       ratingBadgeContainer, {
          "merchant_id": 42,
          "position": "BOTTOM_LEFT"
        });
    });
  }
</script>
<!-- END GCR Badge Code -->

<!-- BEGIN GCR Language Code -->
<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en_US'
  };
</script>


<g:ratingbadge merchant_id=MERCHANT_ID></g:ratingbadge>​
```

But is it even possible to get this working on the local machine?

Also by local machine I mean running the visual studio solution on my computer. So it's not in a publically accessible website.

Cheers

Comment: `But is it even possible to get this working on the local machine` - have you tried? define "local machine"? is it `http://localhost/` or do you mean `file:///...`

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi, yes I have tried it. the badge doesn't show. Also by local machine I mean running the visual studio solution on my computer. So it's not in a publically accessible website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out,

It turns out the badge wont render on the local machine http://localhost

Also the customer reviews code I got from google was implemented throuh google tag manager.
Upon analysis the badge was not rendering, so when I added the customer reviews code into the footer (so not throuh tag manager) it was working.

> Conclusion
>
> The google customer reviews code must be on the live server to
>   work.(So not http://localhost) etc.
>
> The code must be included directly in the theme files. NOT THROUGH
>   GOOGLE TAG MANAGER

Comment: The second part of this is completely false: you can absolutely load these using GTM. Perhaps your triggers were not firing the tag. The first part of this is true: the badge and popup appear to be tied to the domain of the page you load them on. Even when testing on a development server (not localhost, but different hostname than prod), the popup would not appear. In other words: if Google doesn't know your dev hostname, it's not going to load the popup or badge on your dev site. It will show a 404 error in devtools for that HTTP request.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion as the answer here. The badge doesn't work with GTM. The official docs for Customer Reviews explicitly mentions a GTM incompatibility with the [opt-in module](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9352538?hl=en&ref_topic=7105497), although there's no GTM mention with the badge troubleshooting guide. I tried loading the badge via GTM on my production site and it didn't work. The badge did load when adding the code directly to the page, even on a non-production domain.

Comment: @EricSeastrand This page says Google Tag Manager can not be used for this: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9352538?hl=en

Comment: It's been a while - so it's possible this changed, or that my memory fails me. But I distinctly remember implementing this on a site where I was not able to change the HTML directly, which means I'd have used GTM. If you are fortunate enough to have control over the raw HTML, by all means, follow the instructions and don't use GTM :)